# Why my JBoss 5.1.0.GA miss web console tags?

Tags: jboss, jboss5.x

I know JBoss server web console page has some tags on left side of screen.Why my JBoss 5.1.0.GA miss web console tags? See screenshot;

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For display left side of web-console is responsible Java Applet. Maybe you don't have Java Plugin in your browser?

If you use Firefox or Chrome you can check it by input in address bar such command: `about:plugins`.